# Cross Subscription moving of specific Azure resource using Powershell

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, azure-resource-group

I've tried this , but this is for moving resources from RG to RG

`$Resource = Get-AzureRmResource -ResourceType "Microsoft.ClassicCompute/storageAccounts" -ResourceName "ContosoStorageAccount"`

`Move-AzureRmResource -ResourceId $Resource.ResourceId -DestinationResourceGroupName "ResourceGroup14"`

guide me..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following example shows how to move a Azure SQL server to a new resource group.

Login-AzAccount

```
$sqldbserver = Get-AzResource -ResourceGroupName "OLD_RESOURCEGROUP" -ResourceName "SERVERNAME"
```

```
Move-AzResource -ResourceId $sqldbserver.ResourceId -DestinationSubscriptionId "XXXXXXXXXXXXX" -DestinationResourceGroupName "NEW_RESOURCEGROUP"
```

To move to a new subscription, include a value for the `DestinationSubscriptionId` parameter. `[-DestinationSubscriptionId <Guid>]`

Answer (score 1):

If you read [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.resources/move-azurermresource?view=azurermps-6.13.0) for Move-AzureRMResource you will see there is a '-DestinationSubscriptionId' parameter, use this to supply the subscription ID your moving to.